# Assign a Paragraph to a string variable

Tags: c#, string

How can i set the following text to a variable of type string?

```
<li><a href='#M'>M</a></li>
<li><a href='#B'>B</a></li>
<li><a href='#K'>K</a></li>
```

Is there any simple way i can set a string variable with a code similar to the bellow:

```
StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
s.WriteLine("{0}", @"
<li><a href='#M'>M</a></li>
<li><a href='#B'>B</a></li>
<li><a href='#K'>K</a></li>
");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to escape `"` inside your string (do this with a `\`), secondly you either need to make it single line or you need to concatenate each line:

```
StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
// string in single line
s.WriteLine("{0}", 
    "<li><a href=\"#M\">M</a></li><li><a href=\"#B\">B</a></li><li><a href=\"#K\">K</a></li>");

// lines are concatenated
s.WriteLine("{0}", 
    "<li><a href=\"#M\">M</a></li>" +
    "<li><a href=\"#B\">B</a></li>" + 
    "<li><a href=\"#K\">K</a></li>"
);
```

In this case I'd prefer to use single line string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the " with \".

```
s.WriteLine("{0}", 
   "<li><a href=\"#M\">M</a></li><li><a href=\"#B\">B</a></li><li><a href=\"#K\">K</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this? (with newlines)

```
string str = @"<li><a href='#M'>M</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine
                + @"<li><a href='#B'>B</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine
                + @"<li><a href='#K'>K</a></li>";
```

Or the string in one line:

```
string str = @"<li><a href='#M'>M</a></li>" +
               @"<li><a href='#B'>B</a></li>" + 
               @"<li><a href='#K'>K</a></li>";
```

But you have a very high reputation so I'm not sure what you are asking?